# PHP Sendmail - Using HTML Mail with PHP Variable

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I am trying to send an html email each time a user posts a job onto our app.

Below is our php function, which takes a parameter 'job_title' which we want to include in the HTML email that is sent out:

```
require('phpmailer/PHPMailer.php');
require('phpmailer/Exception.php');
require('phpmailer/SMTP.php');
require('phpmailer/POP3.php');
require('phpmailer/OAuth.php');

function sendJobPostedEmail($to, $job_title) {

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'xxxxxx';
$mail->Password   = 'xxxxxx';
$mail->SetFrom('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
$mail->addAddress($to, 'ToEmail');
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Your job has been posted!';
$mail->Body    = file_get_contents("jobposted-email.php");

$mail->send();

return true;

}
```

Here is the html snippet from the email that is sent out:

```
<p class="lead tm"><?php echo $job_title; ?></p>
```

The email is sent out fine, however the variable $job_title is not printed.  Why is my variable not being passed into the included 'jobposted_email.php'?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` will not run the php on a local file

Answer (score 0):

Try placing **ob_start();** before the mail function and then use **include 'jobposted-email.php';**

After, store the contents in a **$body = ob_get_contents();** When the email is sent, do a **ob_end_Clean();**

Example using your code. Let me know if it helps:

```
require('phpmailer/PHPMailer.php');
require('phpmailer/Exception.php');
require('phpmailer/SMTP.php');
require('phpmailer/POP3.php');
require('phpmailer/OAuth.php');

ob_start();
include 'jobposted-email.php';
$body = ob_get_contents();

function sendJobPostedEmail($to, $job_title) {

$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username   = 'xxxxxx';
$mail->Password   = 'xxxxxx';
$mail->SetFrom('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
$mail->addAddress($to, 'ToEmail');
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Your job has been posted!';
$mail->Body    = $body;

$mail->send();

ob_end_Clean();

return true;

}
```